# Execution of background task before app enters to suspended state

Tags: ios, swift, background

I am trying to perform the Finite-Length background task in my app. However, as of now my code is not executed before the app is suspended.

I've followed quite a few tutorials that claims the following to be the way, but obviously I'm getting something wrong. Relevant code should be posted below (please just ask for any clarification if I'm missing something):

```
class Manager {

    private var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

    init(){
        // Add observer able of detecting when app will go to background
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.didEnterBackground(_:)), name: .UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        // Observers removed when view controller is dismissed / deallocated
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

       // Routine performed when app will resign from active
@objc private func didEnterBackground(_ notification: Notification){

    registerBackgroundTask()

    // Code that needs to be executed before app is suspended ------
    DispatchQueue.global().sync {

        self.isBackgrounding = true

        self.shutdownSession()


        self.isConnected = false
        self.isActivated = false
        self.activate = false

        self.connectionManager.closeConnectionToPeripherals()

    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------
    self.endBackgroundTask()

}

func registerBackgroundTask() {
    backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { [weak self] in
        self?.endBackgroundTask()
    }
    assert(backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
}

func endBackgroundTask() {
    print("\n\n\nBackground task ended.\n\n\n")
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}

}
```

I am facing a problem where the background task always seem to be ended before executing the code. How do I ensure that the code in my synchronous block gets executed before app is suspended?

I don't quite understand the "registerBackgroundTask()" either - even though the internet insists on implementing it this way - as it calls the endBackgroundTask().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `self.endBackgroundTask()` call into your DispatchQueue block, right after `self.connectionManager.closeConnectionToPeripherals()`.

The `registerBackgroundTask` method does not directly call `self.endBackgroundTask()`, instead it is only called if the background task expired. Usually, this happens if your app does not complete the task after ~30s in background.

Comment: I rearranged the code to your suggestion, but the "Background task ended." is still executed right away. I know that the task takes approx. 7 seconds in total so something is still wrong.
Could it have anything to do with the fact that I am calling functions and they are thus executed/started, but not finished internally?

Comment: Yes. If the functions that you're calling are doing asynchronous work, the system might freeze your app before they return. If these functions need to be async, then you have to modify them by passing a completion block and execute `endBackgroundTask` as soon as all returned.